# CSS: First child of children with a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="statistics">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>19/06/2015
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> 18 lectures
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> 1 commentaire
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sébastien Sougnez
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart note"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart note"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart note"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart note"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty note"></span>
</div>
```

I'm applying some CSS style and amongst them, I have this :

```
.article .statistics span.note {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.article .statistics span.note:first-child {
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

The first CSS block is correctly applied, the space between all "note" span is about 5px but I'd like to put a margin-left on the first span with the "note" class of 25px, however, the first-child does not seem to select the element which is weird because I also have this CSS :

```
.article .statistics span {
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.article .statistics span:first-child {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

And here, it works fine, all span are separated by 25px (on the left) except the first one. I guess it has something to do with the class but I looked over the Internet and this seems to be the correct syntax.

Thanks

Comment: .article .statistics span:first-child {
    margin-left:0px;
} this will remove your 25px margin

Comment: Hi, I don't see why... However, I removed it (actually it looks better without) and I still have the issue. This selector was for the first span of the div, what I want is a selector for the first span with the "class" note.

Comment: so you want 19/06/2015  span to be 25px left not 0px   ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first `span.note` is not the first child of `.statistics`, so `span.note:first-child` will not match. The first child is a `span` that *doesn't* have the `.note` class, so only the `span:first-child` selector without the class will match, on that child element.

Using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107), apply the left margin to all `span.note` children and then remove it from subsequent ones, instead of trying to apply it separately to the first one:

```
.article .statistics span.note {
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.article .statistics span.note ~ span.note {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Remember to omit the unit when applying a `0` value to a property.

Comment: @connexo: Why does one need to remember to do that? Does leaving the unit in have unintended side effects?

Comment: It saves two bytes! That's gotta be valuable. :)

Comment: @connexo: Also, that should be "when applying a 0 length", because only <length> accepts unitless zeroes (besides <integer>) - no other quantity does.

Comment: @Paulie_D with my answer you don't even need to reverse the margin :)

Comment: @Paulie_D: Oh yeah, why didn't I think of that? :)

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan: That is true. The OP still needs the general rule for margin-right though, which is why I figured I'd use this technique instead to make use of the general rule. But I did +1 yours.

Answer (score 6):

you can straight match the first `span.note` element, like so

```
/* when it is exactly the first child of its parent 
 * (not your specific case)
 */
span.note:first-child,  

/* when it is not the first-child, and then is 
 * preceded by another span whose class is not ".note"
 */
span:not(.note) + span.note {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvdqbR

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand `:first-child`. All this selector asks is "**Am I the first child of my parent?**" - *nothing more*. None of you `span.note` fulfills this.

Answer (score -1):

Try important to this property

```
.article .statistics span:first-child {
    margin-left:0px !important;
}
```